# how to handle format exception for different textboxes with a custom message

Tags: c#, wpf, exception

I am inserting data in my database with a sqlcommand and parameters.All that is in my try {} part..after that I have a catch{} that gets exceptions.
My problem is that I have a date text boxes,and I have a integer texboxes.

How can I have for my date field

```
`catch{FormatException)
{
messagebox.show("Your date field must be dd/mm/yyy");
}
```

and how can I have for my integer field

```
`catch{FormatException)
    {
    messagebox.show("That field must be integer");
    }
```

How can I separate those two format exceptions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both `FormatException`s give different values for the `exc.Message` (where exc is the exception variable). For an `int`, it's "Input string was not in a correct format." and for a `DateTime` it's "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.".

So you *could* just use a single try-catch and check for this string at the end, but that could create problems later on (code becomes hard to maintain). It's better to use separate try-catch blocks.

```
string messageError = null;
string convertTodate = "34/";
string convertToInt = "3.5";
try
{
    int newInt = Convert.ToInt32(convertToInt);
}
catch(FormatException)
{
    messageError = "That field must be integer";
}
try
{
    DateTime newDate = Convert.ToDateTime(convertTodate);
}
catch(FormatException)
{
    messageError = "Your date field must be dd/mm/yyy";
}
if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(messageError))
{
    // All Ok
}
else
{
    // Display error contained witin messageError 
}
```

Comment: but all my sql parameters are in one try {}..I tried to add try in that try with parameters,and it doesn't work then..

Comment: I made it work..But at the end of all my parameters,after that try I have a catch also..And that catches my exception also..Do I just delete it?Or just dont let it show in a message box?

Comment: If you have a try-catch block _inside_ another try-catch, and if the exception is caught in the inner block, then it will not be caught outside also. Maybe it's a different exception, or maybe it's raised from another line of code.

Comment: exceptions says the parameterized query '(....)' expects the parameterer @year that was not supplied.. parameters year is the one that is in a inside try

Comment: @nscott23 That sounds like a sql/database exception. Perhaps the query is incorrect ? You will have to make a new question (along with the code where the exception is thrown) !

Comment: query is correct,because when I insert number in that column,it inserts in the database

Comment: @nscott23 I see. But still would need to look at the code to figure out what's going wrong (Edit : Just saw your new question, glad to see that you've got it working right !)

Answer (score 1):

For date input rather than using textbox, use DatePicker. It will exclude the need to check for the format.

```
<DatePicker name="datePicker"></DatePicker>
```

And to get the value picked by date in behind code,

```
datePicker.SelectedDate
```

Now you only have to check for integer.

```
int parsedValue;
if(int.TryParse(convertToInt, out parsedValue)){ 
    // All Ok
}
else {
     messageError = "That field must be integer";
     // Display error contained witin messageError 
}
```

No need to put try catch as well.

Comment: I think a int.TryParse would be better for the int parse, raising exceptions is slow and a try ... catch slows down the code also

Comment: TryParse is better solution then using only Parse. Unless you want to do something with the exception object, try to avoid the try/catch block in your code. If else is much better and easy approach.